# Derivative of a matrix inverse with respect to a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given some real symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a parameter $\lambda \in\mathbb{R}_+$, I want to differentiate:

$$f(\lambda) = (\lambda \mathrm{Id} + X)^{-1}$$

but I don't know where to start. Clearly $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ but not sure how to handle the inverse.

Comment: The matrix is symmetric. That means your first instinct should be to check if diagonalization helps.

Comment: $f$ is a composition of $\lambda \to \lambda I - X=M \to M^{-1}$ ; therefore use the formula for the derivation of a composite function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential at $P$ of the map $X\mapsto X^{-1}$ is the map $H\mapsto -P^{-1}HP^{-1}$. Therefore by chain rule $(d_\lambda f)(h)=-(\lambda I+X)^{-1}( hI)(\lambda I+X)^{-1}$. I.e., under the indentification of $d_\lambda f$ with the vecotr $f'(\lambda)$ such that $(d_\lambda f)(h)=h f'(\lambda)$ for all $h$, we have $f'(\lambda)=-(\lambda I+X)^{-2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lambda \in\mathbb{R}_+$ and $ \lambda I+X$ be invertible. Then there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $ \lambda$ such that $ \mu I+X$ is invertible for all $ \mu \in U.$

Now show that for $ \mu \in U$ with $ \lambda \ne \mu$ we have

$$\frac{f(\lambda)-f(\mu)}{\lambda - \mu}= -f(\lambda)f( \mu).$$
Can you proceed ?